I want to send updated cart information from a table using jquery
Hello there im making a pos system in laravel. i have a cart for selling the items and its using jquery to send the data. So the issue im having is that when sending the data if my quantity for my product is one its fine. when i post the data the data is received well. but when i increase the quantity to 2 it increases the tax and the total but when i send the data it only sends the information for one item
here is how im adding the product to the cart

    function loadProductsByName(productName) {
    axios.get(`/products/searchByName/${productName}`)
        .then((response) => {
            $("#prodResult").hide();
            const products = response.data.products;  // Accessing products array in the response
            const product = products.length > 0 ? products[0] : null;  // Assuming the response contains an array of products

            if (product) {
                var taxGroup = product.tax;
                var tax;
                var total;
                var unitPrice;
                
                ////
                if(product.price_inc_tax=='No'){
                    unitPrice = product.price;
                    if(taxGroup==0.15){
                    tax=product.price*taxGroup;
                    total=product.price*1.15;
                if(taxGroup=='ex'){
                    tax='-';
                }
                }else{
                    tax=0;
                    total=product.price;
                }

                }else{

                    if(taxGroup==0.15){
                    unitPrice = product.price/1.15;
                    total=product.price;
                    tax=total-unitPrice;
                    
                if(taxGroup=='ex'){
                    unitPrice=product.price;
                    tax='-';
                }
                }else{
                    unitPrice=product.price;
                    tax=0;
                    total=product.price;
                }

                }

                
                ////////
                const existingCartItem = state.cart.find(item => item.id === product.id);
                if (existingCartItem) {
                    // If the product is already in the cart, increase the quantity
                    existingCartItem.quantity += 1;
                } else {
                    // If the product is not in the cart, add it with quantity 1
                    state.cart.push({
                        id: product.id,
                        name: product.name,
                        barcode:product.barcode,
                        tax:tax,
                        unitPrice:unitPrice,
                        total:parseFloat(total), // Assuming price is a string, convert it to a number
                        quantity: 1,
                    });
                }
                // Update the user interface with the product information
                updateCartUI();
            } else {    

                showAlert('Product Not Found',"error");
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Handle errors here
            console.error('Error loading products:', error);
        });
    }

    function showAlert(message,errorIconMessage){
        Swal.fire({
                position: "top-end",
                icon: errorIconMessage,
                title: message,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1000
               });    
    
     }

here is the updateCartUI function that will update the cart with the values

 function updateCartUI() {
    const cartTableBody = $(".user-cart table tbody");
    cartTableBody.empty();
    state.cart.forEach((item) => {
        const rowHtml = `
        <tr>
    <td>${item.name}</td>   
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input
                type="number"
                class="form-control border border-2 py-1 px-2 quantity-input"
                value="${item.quantity}"
                id="quantityField"
                data-product-id="${item.id}"
            />    
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>${item.barcode}</td>    
    <td class="tax-input">${(item.tax * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</td>  
    <td>${item.unitPrice.toFixed(2)}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg py-1 px-2 remove-item" data-product-id="${item.id}">
                <i class="fas fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right" >${(item.total * item.quantity).toFixed(2)}</td>
</tr>
        `;
        cartTableBody.append(rowHtml);  
        
        });

        $(".remove-item").on("click", function () {
    const productId = $(this).data("product-id");
    removeCartItem(productId);
});

//when im selling im sending it in this manner
$("#sellForm").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Check if there are items in the cart
    if (state.cart.length === 0) {
        showAlert('Cart is empty', 'error');
        return;
    }

    // Collect total value
    const totalValue = $("#totalValue").val();

    // Collect amount paid
    const amountPaid = $("#amountPaid").val();

    // Calculate change
    const change = amountPaid - totalValue;

    // Create a hidden form element
    const sellForm = document.createElement('form');
    sellForm.method = 'POST';
    sellForm.action = '/sell';

    // Append total value, amount paid, and change as hidden fields
    sellForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="total" value="' + totalValue + '">';
    sellForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="amount_paid" value="' + amountPaid + '">';
    sellForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="change" value="' + change + '">';

    // Append sale items including quantity and tax as hidden fields
    state.cart.forEach(item => {
    const row = $(".user-cart").find("[data-product-id='" + item.id + "']").closest("tr");
    const updatedQuantity = row.find(".quantity-input").val(); // Get the updated quantity
    const updatedTax = row.find(".tax-input").text(); // Get the updated tax
    const updatedTotal = row.find(".text-right").text(); // Get the updated total
    sellForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="sale_items[' + item.id + '][quantity]" value="' + updatedQuantity + '">';
    sellForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="sale_items[' + item.id + '][tax]" value="' + updatedTax + '">';
    sellForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="sale_items[' + item.id + '][total]" value="' + updatedTotal + '">';
});

    // Append the form to the document body and submit
    document.body.appendChild(sellForm);
    sellForm.submit();
});

So in this case its not sending the updated data but only the quantity for one item
ive tried sending the product as an array from the form but its not working

Regedzai kupindura masaskam zvaita hamubatsire
